# Why won't my code run my IF-ELSE statement correctly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
function checkPIN(pin) {
  if (isNaN(pin)) {
    console.log(pin, ' is not a number');
  } else {
    console.log(pin, ' is a number');
  }  
}

checkPIN(12sf34);
```

Still quite new to this and cannot for the life of me work out why i can't get a simple check of whether something is a number or not to work?

At the moment i'm getting two errors:

On the above:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

And on a similar piece of code, it accepts that something is a number and runs my con-log. But when it's NOT a number, it gives an 'undefined' to the letters/not-a-number value.

Can i not use isNaN in a function? 
Is there a reason why i need an extra bracket/parenthesis somewhere? I cannot for the life of me see a requirement for an extra one.

Comment: And what is `12sf34` ? Did you intend to put some quotes around that.

Comment: It's not a number, it's a string. You have to pass it as so or it's gonna die.

Comment: `12sf34` is a SyntaxError

Comment: Unrelated to direct issue, but use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) instead. The direct issue has already been answered.

Comment: @ASDFGerte `Number.isNaN` detects NaN. It doesn't detect if something is a number.

Comment: @Oriol ah sorry, true. But i'd much prefer a `typeof` check followed by `Number.isNaN` than standard `isNaN`. E.g. `isNaN("37")` might not be what one wants.

Comment: I guess that depends on wether you want to check if something is of type Number or if it's just numeric

Comment: Thanks Adeneo - i put comments around it and it worked. I was keen to get it to handle an unknown variable though? Because presumably functions won't always be called with quotes around the argument you're passing through?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes around the ***string***

```
checkPIN("12sf34");
```

Had it been a number, you wouldn't need quotes, but `12sf34` is clearly not a number

Answer (score 0):

I would use typeof to have more flexibility of testing different types of variables. But the given is not a number so it needs quotations.

```
function checkPIN(pin) {
  if (typeof(pin) != "number") {
    console.log(pin, ' is not a number');
  } else {
    console.log(pin, ' is a number');
  }  
}

checkPIN('12sf34');
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation about the changes that you've made, rather than just posting a blob of code.

Comment: `12sf34` is a SyntaxError

Comment: @Oriol Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes when calling checkPIN function.

Call it like this:

```
checkPIN('12sf34');
```

Comment: how is yours different from @adeneo

Comment: It's the same but by the time I wrote my answer, he answered the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think your code has 2 incorrect points

1. checkPIN(12sf34); // syntax error, need single quote wrap value
2. logic inside checkPIN function should use typeof to check input type

```js
function checkPIN(pin) {
  if (typeof(pin) !== 'number') {
    console.log(`${pin} is not a number`)
  } 
  else {
    console.log(`${pin} is a number`);
  }  
}

checkPIN('abc1d') // abc1d is not a number
checkPIN(12345) // 12345 is a number
checkPIN('12345') // 12345 is not a number
checkPIN() // undefined is not a number
```